# entities inheritance in spring data

Tags: spring-boot, orm, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, mapping

i'm working on a simple application to learn how to work with spring boot/hibernate , and i'm using spring security with system of Role/Users , so i have an entity called User , another one called Roles .

for my application i have two types of users :

1. Admin with attributes ( id , username , password)
2. client with attributes (id , username , password , email , phoneNumber)

that's why i decided to use the concept of inheritance in spring data with creating an Entity User with attributes (id,username,password) and the Client Entity which inherites the Entity User and has the others attributes(id,email,phoneNumber).

in this app , the client can add/remove/ .. some products that exists in my database Mysql , so i wanted to implement a mapping of (one to many / many to one) between entity client and entity product.

now how should i implement this (ORM SIDE), i mean should i do the mapping between entity Client and Product OR between User and Product?

if there is any other better solution i'll be so thankfull :) .

EDIT  :

```
     @Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private String username;
    private String password;
    private String prenom;
    private String nom;
    private Long Tel;
    private String CIN;
    private String Email ;
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Collection<AppRole> roles = new ArrayList<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="client_id")
    private User Client;


    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id")
    private User Manager;


           }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a single table 'user' and 2 roles 'ADMIN' and 'CLIENT'. I would recommend that both user types should have same details including email address and phone number. So when the user logs in, you can load user roles/granted authorities from userdetails service.

**EDIT:**
Your user table should look like

id , username , password , email , phoneNumber, added_by_id

the added_by_id is a self join and references to the user.id column.

so in your entity class, you will do something like the following.

```
...
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "added_by_id")
protected User addedBy;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer first  , and yes after authentication i can get the type of the user authenticated from userdetails Service , i used inheritance , so i created two entites (client , user) , user entity  with the annotation @inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE) ,is this what you meant by Single table ? can you please explain to me more .

Comment: any specific reason you want to use inheritance and have 2 tables instead of one?

Comment: No there is no reason , but please can you explain to me more?  and for the mapping between 'Client' and product , now i should do a mapping between User and product right ? as you advice me to use only one table .and one more question , the admin should add/remove Clients , so am i supposed to have one to many between users and users ?

Comment: hey brother for exemple when i want to insert data into Entity User , what should i insert into the last attribute ? added_by_id ? i get an error , the compilator is waiting for an object of type User

Comment: leave it null for the admin user. next time, an admin user creates a client user, populate this field with the admin's reference.

Comment: sorry for not explaining everything in the post , i have Client ,Manager and admin ,as the admin can add/remove clients and also manager i updated the entity if you can see the post i've edited it right now . for admin's reference , you mean the Object ? for exemple User adminRef = new User(....) ; and then while creating the client i populate the field with 'adminRef ' right ?